# aws dynamodb global secondary index cannot query existing items

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb

E.g:
**myTable**:
**id** **field1**
1   guy

id as the primary key and field1 as the global secondary index:

```
    - AttributeName: id
      KeyType: HASH

  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: Field1Index
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: field1
          KeyType: HASH
```

when i use
`dynamodb.scan()`
or
`dynamodb.get({TableName: 'myTable', Key: {id: 1}})`
can find this record,
But when I use

```
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#field1': 'field1'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":field1": field1
        },
        KeyConditionExpression: "#field1 = :field1",
        IndexName: "Field1Index",})
```

At the time, early data can be found, but recent data cannot be found.

I don't know if it has something to do with myTable's data volume exceeding 8000, but I still have to say it in advance, and I have to add that the data of this table is always written into the data table through batch upload.

At present, what I suspect is that this data does not seem to be registered in the secondary index. There are 8,357 items in the data table and 7,599 items in the secondary index. Therefore, it can be determined that the missing items in the secondary index cannot be queried. data.

At the same time, I also tried to delete the problem data first, and then try to add it again
Problem still can't be solved

Can anyone know what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this, but there may be various warnings due to java version issues
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.ViolationDetection.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).